# In Cucumber, how do you iterate through the feature for multiple locales?

Tags: java, testing, cucumber

I need to test many locales and determine if the app is blocking the correct locales, if the correct information is present for certain locales, etc.

As far as I can tell, Cucumber doesn't offer a way to iterate through given input lists, i.e. 'run this test for US, CA, JP, GB...' and the only way I can think of doing it is to have the test in a single function that loops over the countries in code - this would mean a failure in one locale results in a total failure for that specific test, as well as being very ugly

Is there a good way of running a cucumber feature in a way that I could have a separate test result for each locale, without having to write the test itself 60+ times with a different 'Given I have a {locale} account'?

I'd ideally like to do something like 'For every country in the list {invalidCountries} do {test}'

Answer (score 2):

You can do it two ways

First, you can use Scenario outline : https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-Outlines (with the language in the examples list.

Other way : you can make all the tests with a variable (ex: "I open the app in 'US' language" as a first step), and then pass the language via the command line. 
Example : cucumber LAN=US
Then you just need to set the variable at the launch of your test.

Answer (score 1):

Locale can be implement by installing I18 gem. visit [I18n testing with Cucumber](http://hackers.lookout.com/2012/09/multilingual-pickles/).

```
Then /^I should be greeted$/ do
  page.should have_content(I18n.t('dashboard.welcome', :name => first_name))
end
```

like this,

hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all try and write the feature you would like to have in abstract language. Concentrate on the WHAT and WHY, rather than the HOW. If you can explain why you are trying to do this, the you'll get a better answer about how to do it.

Generally for this kind of problem the solution is to "push the how down". This means that you do all your looping in your step definitions. You can make the particular step definition that does the work elegant by delegating the work to a helper method e.g. (assumes ruby)

```
When "I do something with each blocked locale" do
  do_something(locales: blocked_locales)
end

module LocaleStepHelper 
  def do_something
    ...
  end
end
World LocaleStepHelper
```

You can make the method that does all the work elegant, by using your standard programming skills. This is much easier than trying to do this in Cucumber.

Summary: don't try and program in Cucumber, push all programming down, remove the how from scenarios and concentrate on the what and why

Comment: So I just want to go to a page, click one button and verify that I'm on a different page, but I want to do that for many locales. In your example, would the do_something include the initial load of the page, the click and the verification of the load? That doesn't seem right to me, because if any one of the countries fail, the whole test would fail. Since I have to do this for many tests, they would all be very brittle, and finding the actual root cause would be a lot harder.

Comment: Think of it this way, you want to do an action (navigate_from_foo_to_bar), and you want to do this for lots of things, and you want to collect results. So write a method for the action that provides a result. Then iterate over the locales, collecting the result for each action. Finally report on the results. If you don't want the test to fail until all the locales have been tested, don't throw exceptions in your action. After you have got your results then you can throw the exception if you have a bad result.